# insertion in a binary tree in C

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-tree

The below code is running but after taking the second number to insert into the tree, the program is crashing.Why is it so? user input 1 is for inserting and 0 is for exit
Thanks in advance...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct ll
{
 int data;
 struct ll *left;
 struct ll *right;
}node;
void insert(node **root,int n)
{
 if((*root)==NULL)
 {
  (*root)=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  (*root)->data=n;
 }
 else if(((*root)->data)<n)
 {
  insert(&(*root)->right,n);
 }
 else if(((*root)->data)>n)
 {
  insert(&(*root)->left,n);
 }
}
main()
{
 node *head=NULL;int choice,n;
 while(1)
 {
 printf("Enter 1 to insert node\n 0 to exit\n");
 scanf("%d",&choice);
 switch(choice)
 {
  case 1: printf("Enter number\n");
          scanf("%d",&n);
         insert(&head,n);break;
  case 0:exit(0);
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger show you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialise the `left` or `right` members when you allocate a new `node`

```
 if((*root)==NULL)
 {
  (*root)=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  (*root)->data=n;
 }
```

allocates a `node` but leaves its `left` and `right` members pointing to unpredictable values.  When you allocate a second `node`, `insert` will try to dereference one of these values.  This results in undefined behaviour; sooner or later you'll get a crash after attempting to dereference an address that isn't readable by your code or is incorrectly aligned.

You can avoid this by initialising all members of a new `node`:

```
if((*root)==NULL)
{
    (*root)=malloc(sizeof(node));
    (*root)->data=n;
    (*root)->left=NULL;
    (*root)->right=NULL;
}
```

Alternatively, you could allocate memory using `calloc`, to initialise the new `node`'s members to `0`

```
if((*root)==NULL)
{
    (*root)=calloc(1, sizeof(node));
    (*root)->data=n;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working.But shouldn't dereferenced pointers take a NULL value?

Comment: `malloc` returns a block of memory but doesn't initialise it to any known value.  You could however use `calloc` to initialise all memory for a `node` to 0, effectively `NULL`ing its pointers.  I'll update my answer to cover this.